# convert script output from columns to rows

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

i have file conatin data like this

```
tcp,0,5,server1,1221,server5,0
udp,0,7,server2,4324,server1,0
tcp,2,1,server3,2355,server4,0
```

the below my script trial

```
while true; do
if [[ $first == "2" ]] ; then
read -p "Please input the src IP pattern: " sstr
cat temp | awk -F',' -v pat="$sstr" 'tolower($4) ~ pat {print $4}' 
fi 
if [[ $second == "4" ]] ; then
read -p "Please input the dest IP pattern: " dstr
cat temp | awk -F',' -v pat="$dstr" 'tolower($6) ~ pat {print $6}' 
fi
break
done > $destfile
```

the output like

```
src 
server1
server2
server3
dest
server5
server1
server4
```

i want it to be like this

```
src dest
server1 server5
server2 server1
server3 server4
```

Comment: the `paste` command may be of use

Comment: What is the output supposed to be when `$first != 2` or `$second != 4`  (or both)?

Comment: Also, the output you show has the same number of values coming from the fourth and sixth comma-separated fields (3 and 3). What is supposed to happen when `tolower($4) ~ pat` and `tolower($6) ~ pat` don't match the same number of rows? Your script doesn't seem to allow us to infer it.

Answer (score 1):

Do this entirely in awk, in one pass through the file, not by piping the same file through awk multiple times.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# accept src and dst from command line args
# very primitive.  use getopts to do this properly.
[ -n "$1" ] && sstr="$1"
[ -n "$2" ] && dstr="$2"

# if not provided on command line, ask for them
[ -z "$sstr" ] && read -p "Please input the src IP pattern: " sstr
[ -z "$dstr" ] && read -p "Please input the dst IP pattern: " dstr

awk -F, -v src="$sstr" -v dst="$dstr" '
  BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1; print "src dst"};
  $4 ~ src && $6 ~ dst { print $4,$6 }' temp
```

Output:

```
$ ./print-both-columns.sh 1 5
src dst
server1 server5
```